How can I connect my thick wires into an ikea wire connector
I have thick wires that can not be twisted into one hole of the wire connector, so can I split the wire into two section and feed them into the connector?



It might be helpful to state your country - this is a US centric website, and readers will assume you are in the US. But your wire colours look European. And some potential fixes (like wire nuts) are not normally used in Europe.

WHY are you doing this? The fact that one of the cables appears to be rated for high current and the other is not is highly suspicious.

@MarkMorganLloyd Surely it's a lighting fixture.

@Brad It's undoubtedly a lighting fixture connector which is being used. Is the heavy connector leading to something taking power (which might imply that it wants something like 10A) or from a plug (in which case is it realistically fused)? I'm concerned that the thick lead is connected to say a pre-wired UK 13A plug, with a 13A fuse in it.

@MarkMorganLloyd what are you getting at? The lamp won't draw 13A and IKEA lamps are also allowed to be connected to German 16A fuses with those small cables.

@DonQuiKong The lamp won't draw 13A, which means its fuse should be more realistic. If the lamp does draw more than the 5A its connectors are rated for, because of a fault, the 13A fuse won't protect it from overheating, even if the flex in the picture could cope with that current. What this does mean is that the flex is wrong and it's that which should be changed (along with an appropriate fuse).

This fixture looks like it's designed for permanent installation and wants to connect to one or two (for daisy-chaining) lighting cables, not a flex.

@AndrewLeach That would all be perfectly valid if this was in the UK, but as far as I know, UK is decidedly in the minority in Europe when it comes to putting fuses into plugs. Most if not all of continental Europe uses unfused cords, the fuse is in the device itself.

LHS looks like an LED transformer, RHS is a heavy duty flex.
Assume the OP wants to make their lamp plug in, rather then hardwired into lighting circuit. I would get some thinner flex, 1mm2 is good for 10A.

You can instead replace the IKEA connector with another one that will accept the thick stranded wire on one end and the wire inside the box.

good luck finding a connector that fits in the Ikea custom made space

That looks like a decent sized box so a standard old shool "shugarcube" connector looks like it will fit,

You can use Wago 221, works with stranded and solid core, available in two sizes (normal for 0.14-4mm² and large for 0.5-6mm²), and in two different shapes:



Do not do this. The contacts are designed, tested and CE rated for one whole cable to go into one hole, using them differently to this will invalidate your insurance. For high current applications, you may have split unevenly and it can overheat; you can't do a tug test that it has clamped correctly on both sides; you can't guarantee there won't be stray strands that might cause a shock hazard.
Either get a suitable terminal block, or use a reducing ferrule on the stranded end that can then fit into the terminal you have. (Unless you're in the habit of putting ferrules on cables, getting the right terminal block will be cheaper as ferrules always seem to come in packets of 1000)

This is why civilization is collapsing

Replace the thick wire with one that has conductors of appropriate size for the connector in  IKEA lamp.

You can also use wire nut (aka wire connector) with one thick wire and one or two thiner wires.
This type of Ikea connector prefers solid not stranded wires.

Found in many stores like wire nut

To paraphrase, "add a pigtail to phase and neutral incoming wire, which splits to two smaller solid-core wires per side"  ?

@MichaelHarvey don't forget to ask for the special wire nuts for earth connections, called "ground nuts".

While uncommon across the pond, this is still a valid answer and shouldn't be down voted.

Cut off 1/3 to 1/2 of the strands, twist what's left, shove it into the hole, make sure there are no loose strands outside and do the tug test.
Ignore the fearmongers, the connector will be the weakest point of the whole setup and that won't change whatever coble or ferrule you use.

While the practical answer, it's probably not code or insurance compliant. The latter is a concern but the former is something people here tend to stick to.

@cde "People here" are the reason regulation turns into overregulation, chipping away at civilization's legs
